# Spray json parsing and NullPointerException

Tags: json, scala, nullpointerexception, spray-json

i'm got an error:

```
spray.json.ProductFormats$class.productElement2Field NullPointerException
```

Here is my code for json deserialisation:

```
object DomainJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
implicit val loginInfoFormat = jsonFormat(LoginInfo, "userid", "email", "password", "rememberme")
implicit val requestStatusFormat = jsonFormat(RequestStatus, "status", "message")
implicit val requestHolderFormat = jsonFormat(RequestHolder, "requestStatus", "loginInfo")
}

case class RequestHolder(requestStatus : RequestStatus, loginInfo: LoginInfo) {
  def this(requestStatus : RequestStatus) = this(requestStatus, null)
}
case class LoginInfo(userid: Int, email: String, password: String, rememberme: Boolean)
case class RequestStatus(status : Int, message: String)

val requestHolder = content.asJson.convertTo[RequestHolder] //The error is hereHere is
```

I guess it could be because of the overloaded constructors in the class RequestHolder.

upd: 
The json content is:

```
{"requestStatus":{"status":0,"message":""},"loginInfo":{"userid":0,"email":"123","password":"123","rememberme":false}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm found solution in the official spray mailing list, the solution is use Option[MyClass] = None in the constructor, instead the override constructors with nulls, for instance, my class definition look like:

```
case class RequestHolder(requestStatus : RequestStatus,  loginInfo: Option[LoginInfo] = None)
```

and now parsing works fine!

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and my problem was due to the order I defined the jsonreaders. I had an example like this:

```
implicit val multipleThings: RootJsonFormat[Things] = jsonFormat1(Things)
implicit val singleThing: RootJsonFormat[Thing] = jsonFormat1(Thing)
```

Here the `Things` case class had a list of `Thing`'s.

That didn't work because the first one implicitly needs the second one. Reordering them like this:

```
implicit val singleThing: RootJsonFormat[Thing] = jsonFormat1(Thing)
implicit val multipleThings: RootJsonFormat[Things] = jsonFormat1(Things)
```

Made it work.

All credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280316/1539208

Comment: This is even helpful now in 2021. I guess it should be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and for me it was lazyFormat that fixed it:

```
implicit val requestStatusFormat: JsonFormat[RequestStatus] = lazyFormat(jsonFormat2(RequestStatus))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the show.
In my case the order of declarations mattered (and fixed the NPE issue):

```
trait ValuesProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val valRangeFormat: JsonFormat[ValRange] = jsonFormat2(ValRange)
  implicit val specificValFormat: JsonFormat[SpecificVal] = jsonFormat1(SpecificVal)
  implicit val baseValFormat: JsonFormat[BaseVal] = BaseValFormat
  implicit val totalFormat: JsonFormat[Total] = jsonFormat4(Total)
}
```

This is what the JSON code was supposed to look like:

```
  val json1 = """
      |{
      |"title": "json1",
      |"values": [{
      |"minValue": 100,
      |"maxValue": 100.5},
      |{
      |"value": 300.7
      |}]
      |}
      |""".stripMargin
```

The entire JSON is called Total - a case class, BaseVal is an empty class inherited by case classes ValRange and SpecificVal